# Most correct collection type for contracts?

Tags: c#

Let's talk ASP.NET controllers, internal command/query handlers, etc.

Is there a de-facto/recommended type of collection to use for requests/parameters and responses/results?

#### Arrays

I've always liked this - in requests, the method says I want a fixed set of items.  The reponse says, here's a fixed set of items.

But, `ToArray()` can have and overhead, and most work you do is likely to *not* end up producing an array.

#### IEnumerable<>

Seems a good way to go, though feels more 'mysterious'?  And Resharper gives a billion warnings about possible multiple enumeration of them.  There's a chance that enumerating might have side-effects, too.

#### List<>, IList<>, ICollection<>

All have `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear` methods.  To me, means that data contracts could or should be modified.  I feel that contracts should be immutable?  If a method returns something with an `Add` method, kind of breaks the idea that the operation was pure/atomic/something like that?

#### IReadOnlyCollection<>, IReadOnlyList<>

Actually seem to be a pretty good answer.  The List variant allows grabbing by index, not strictly necessary.  Downside is the best one (collection) request extra code to wrap up, because arrays, lists and the like don't inherit `IReadOnlyCollection`.

Ideally I guess there would have been an `IReadableCollection` with read methods, and `IWriteableCollection` with mutation methods.

So, how do we remove the subjective factor here.

**My specific question: Is there a de-facto or recommended route?**

Comment: I would strongly suggest **not** using `IList` - since the fact that array implements it (and doesn't implement `Add`) makes it largely useless. Use `IReadOnlyList` in preference.

Comment: I don't see how this is too broad - please advise.  It's really quite specific?

Comment: I suspect some of the close requests were for 'primarily opinion based'. In other words, there is unlikely to be broad consensus on the answer to the question (just a variety of opinions, such as my opinion in my above comment).

Comment: Yeah, I'd be closing for opinion based if it were still open. The only one I'd say "no" to is `Array`. Unless you're writing some form of collection class yourself, it doesn't have a place in most code in 2018. It's very *mechanism* focussed (and a weird mechanism of a fixed-size collection with mutable content)

Comment: `because arrays, lists and the like don't inherit IReadOnlyCollection.` Arrays and lists both implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Comment: I couldn't see that in any msdn documentation, thanks @mjwills. If anyone knows a reasonable place to ask this question, please let me know..